# Selecting all unassigned vertices?

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups

I'm rigging a model, and I'd like to hide all of the vertices I've already assigned to vertex groups. Is there a way I can quickly select either all vertices that are assigned to various vertex groups, or all vertices that have not yet been assigned to a vertex group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In edit mode, you can select ungrouped vertices:

[image]

Also available in weight paint mode when vertex selection is enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With your object selected, go to the object properties tab, select the vertex group you want to see from the list, and click the "select" button (or deselect, depending on what you want to do). You must be in edit mode to see the selection.

[image: VertexSelect]